# Exclude subdomain from 301 redirect

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I am trying to exclude the halcyondaysws subdomain from all my 301 redirects but can't manage it. I tried it like this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^halcyondaysws\.maindomain\.net
RewriteRule .* - [S=7]
Redirect 301 /enamels.html http://www.halcyondays.co.uk/enamels/christening-nursery.html
```

and this

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?maindomain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule /enamels.html http://www.maindomain.co.uk/enamels/christening-nursery.html [L,R=301]
```

But it doesn't work. We are using only one `.htaccess` file.

Comment: You mean, "subdomain", not "subdirectory". (?)

Comment: @w3d yes, subdomain, my bad

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To **exclude a particular domain** use this negation based condition:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^halcyondaysws\.maindomain\.net$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^enamels\.html$ http://www.maindomain.co.uk/enamels/christening-nursery.html [L,R=301,NC]
```

And test this after clearing browser cache.

Please understand this is not really excluding a sub-directory. Since your rule is targeting `/enamels.html` hence there is no need to exclude a sub-directory.

Comment: Thanks for answering. wouldn't this work for any subdomain? I want to exclude only halcyondaysws subdomain